# How does Fabric.js render text?

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I have an issue with the output of fonts, and I'm unsure of the cause.

In the browser, fonts can be made bold and italic (and both), but on a node.js server the bold/italic is ignored completely.

I believe this is because Fabric.js relays the rendering to the native HTML5 canvas, meaning that the rendering of fonts is essentially done by the browser's engine and that would explain the difference between the output of the browsers compared to the node.js server.

But I am getting lost in the code... I was wondering if anyone by chance has in-depth knowledge of procedure. This is what I think happens:

- Developer sets the font weight to bold
- Fabric.js creates a DOMString and passes it to native canvas
- Native canvas lets the browser's engine render the DOMString

Is this what's happening?

Comment: Try use useNative property to false and render text with cufon: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#useNative

Comment: Check this tutorial https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/How-to-render-text-with-Cufon-(deprecated) and about cufon - generator: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/How-to-render-text-with-Cufon-(deprecated) - cufon fonts: http://www.cufonfonts.com/

Comment: Alright, so that would work. But what if cufon is not an option?

Comment: Check this: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/ (Custom fonts in Fabric on Node)

Comment: Yeah I am adding different font files, but that is besides the point. I would like to understand the process better! :)

Comment: For most fonts in respect to web usage, there is a different file for the regular, bold, italic, etc. variations.  So while a browser can handle this, NodeJS needs the specific font files to be defined and loaded for each styling variation.  You'll need to load each of the font files and reference them accordingly.